# How should I call this function? I need a function which returns a tuple

Tags: haskell

I've got one problem with this code :

```
append (first, second) f  = (first ++ fst(f second), snd(f second))
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't know how to call this function, because I don't understand how to match the `^`-marked functions correctly. In my opinion, I need a function which returns a tuple, because function fst require this.

Comment: If my edit changed the meaning of your post, feel free to re-edit it.

Comment: Thanks I tried bold this function, but it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, you can't use formatting (bold, italics, etc) inside code blocks.

Comment: Anyway, can you describe (in words) what exactly you want the `append` function to do?

Comment: Well, what is the type of `append`? What arguments have you tried to pass to `append`? What functions have you tried to build that match `append`'s argument types? Generally: what did you do, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you rewrite a little your expression with explicit pattern matching and sharing, things become clearer :

```
append :: ([w], a) -> (a -> ([w], b)) -> ([w], b)
append (w, a) f  = let (w', b) = f a
                   in  (w ++ w', b)
```

So you take a tuple with a list and a value, apply a function producing another list. The list is appended to the original list and the value replace the previous one in the tuple.

It seems that you reinvented the `((,) w)` monad aka the writer monad !

Look a the type of `>>=` (bind), it applies a function to a momadic value producing another monadic value :

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Now if you replace `m` by `((,) w)` (or `(w,)` if the notation for tuple sections was allowed in types), such that `m a` became `(w, a)`, you get :

```
bindSpecialized :: (w, a) -> (a -> (w, b)) -> (w, b)
```

However `((,) w)` can only be used as a monad if we have a way to combine `w`s. You achieved that with lists and `++`. A more general approach is to use the type class [`Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) for type with an associative operation and an identity element.

For some reasons, `((,) w)` is not a monad defined in the prelude, it's recommended to use a newtype:

```
newtype Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (w, a) }

instance Functor (Writer w) where
  fmap f (Writer (w, a)) = Writer (w, f a)

instance Monoid w => Monad (Writer w) where
  return a = Writer (mempty, a)
  (Writer (w, a)) >>= f = let Writer (w', b) = f a
                          in  Writer (w <> w', b)

tell :: Monoid w => w -> Writer w ()
tell w = Writer (w, ())

-- test == ("hello world", 3)
test :: (String, Int)
test = runWriter $ do
    a <- test1
    b <- test2
    return $ a + b
  where
    test1 = tell "hello" >> return 1
    test2 = tell " world" >> return 2
```

For practical programs, you should use the `Writer` type and its monad instance already defined in [`Control.Monad.Trans.Writer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Strict.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't have monads on my study yet and that why i had problem with this. Thanks once again.